# python 3 How to print on a previous input line

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I know you can print on the previous line by using end="" e.g

```
import time

print("Loading",end="")
for i in range(3):
    print(".",end="")
```

but is there a way to do it with an input, as it comes up with an error.
e.g the user is asked a question then they input an answer and it prints a ✘ or ✔ next to the input.

```
#Doesn't work
print("What is the capital of england?")
ans = input("+-> ",end="")

if ans == "London":
    print("✔")
else:
    print("✘")
```

This by not be using end="" but a different way?

PS \r and \b don't work

Comment: If you want something like that you should use ncurses

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using [*ANSI/VT100 Terminal Control Escape Sequences*](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#cursor)

```
In [103]: def ask():
              CURSOR_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
              ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'
              message = "What is the capital of england? "
              answer = input(message)
              if answer == "London":
                  print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE + message + answer + "✔")
              else:
                  print(CURSOR_UP_ONE + ERASE_LINE + message + answer + "✘")
   .....: 

In [104]: ask()
What is the capital of england? Paris✘
```

Answer (score 0):

Until you use a new line after your input, Python will not read STDIN to take the input.

So, You can't print the message right after the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit not clear.But as far my understanding below is the answer.

```
print("what is capital of England")
inp = input()

if(inp =="London"):
    print(inp+"->✔")
else:
    print(inp+"->✘")
```

Comment: Thank you but I would like the ✘ or ✔ to be printed on the same line as the input, not the the user's answer reprinted on the next line with the ✘ or ✔.